# Piping the output of powershell to the object id

Tags: powershell, pipe

Having issues with a powershell command, I'm trying to bulk license a group of users but I'm having difficulties getting the output of one command to be the input of another and insight would be greatly appreciated

I first tried

```
Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly -City "city name" | ForEach {Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses "Account SKU"}
```

then I tried

```
Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly -City "City Name" | select-object UserprincipalName | ForEach {Set-MsolUserLicense -Userprincipalname <String> -AddLicenses "Account SKU ID"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly -City "City Name" |
ForEach {
    Set-MsolUserLicense -Userprincipalname $_.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses "Account SKU ID"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Generally***, you only need the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `foreach`):

- for target cmdlets that do *not* support direct input from the pipeline [with the specific objects provided]
- for custom processing of each input object with multiple expressions or commands in a *script block* (`{ ... }`), inside of which automatic variable `$_` represents the input object at hand.

***Specifically*, in your case you do *not* need a `ForEach-Object` call**, and while you still *can* make it work with such a call, as shown in [TessellatingHeckler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751131/45375), it is not only needlessly verbose but also significantly *slower*.

[`Get-MsolUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0#outputs) outputs objects of type `[Microsoft.Online.Administration.User]`, and [`Set-MsolUserLicense`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0)'s `-UserPrincipalName` parameter is designed to implicitly bind to such objects via their `.UserPrincipalName` property, so that you can **simply pipe `Get-MsolUser` output *directly* to `Set-MsolUserLicense`**:

```
Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly -City "city name" |
  Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses "Account SKU ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the foreach you can get access to the current element using

```
$_
```

So you can access any property of the current element using the following syntax:

```
$_.PropertyYouNeed
```